# Hilbert space operators in $V⊗V^\dagger$ and $V⊗V$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, tensor-calculus, linear-algebra

Every operator in Hilbert space is defined in space $V⊗V^\dagger$ respectively

$$A=\sum_{ij}a_{ij}|i\rangle\langle j|$$

But identical operator when we can defined in space $V⊗V$ as

$$A=\sum_{ij}a_{ij}|i\rangle|j\rangle$$

How do this, because $|i\rangle\langle j|$ is matrix, and $|i\rangle|j\rangle$ is column vector?

Comment: The operators/tensors are obviously not "identical" because they live in different spaces. I'm not sure what your question here is - is the last sentence missing a verb?

Comment: I think that representations of operators are identical !

Comment: A operator $O\in A\otimes B^*$ sends elements of $B$ to elements of $A$. So, unless $B^*=B$, $O\in A\otimes B^*$ and $O'\in A\otimes B$ cannot be identical, they can't act on or give result to same arguments. It really doesn't matter how you represent them since you can't even add them together

Comment: Your first $A$ is an operator but your second is a state.  Operators act on states, and send one states to another.  States do not act on anything.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to clarify the meanings of both expressions, I will come to physics but first some math to understand this better. I assume you know what a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ is, i.e. a triple $(H,+,\cdot)$ with $+: H \times H \rightarrow H$ and $\cdot: \mathbb{C} \times H \rightarrow H$, where $\mathbb{C}$, $+$ and $\cdot$ satisfy the axioms for being a field of characteristic zero resp. the axioms for the vector space addition and scalar multiplication. A complex Hilbert space $(H,+,\cdot)$ additionally has an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: H \times H \rightarrow H$ such that for all $\phi,\chi \in H$: $\langle \phi,\chi \rangle = \langle \chi,\phi \rangle^\star$, sesquilinearity (so linear in second slot and antilinear in the first), $\langle \chi,\chi \rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle \chi,\chi \rangle = 0$ if and only if $\phi = 0$. This inner product needs to be complete. This means that every Cauchy sequence $\phi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow H$ written as $\{\phi_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ needs to converge in the Hilbert space. A Cauchy sequence means $\phi: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow H$ such that $\forall \epsilon >0: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}:\forall n,m \geq N: \sqrt{\langle \phi_n-\phi_m, \phi_n-\phi_m \rangle}<\epsilon$ where  $\phi_n:= \phi(n)$ is used) converges in $H$: $\exists \phi \in H: \forall \epsilon>0: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}:\forall n \geq N: \sqrt{\langle \phi - \phi_n,\phi-\phi_n\rangle} < \epsilon$.

From this one can define the dual of the Hilbert space $H$ denoted $H^\star$. $H^\star$ consists of (I ignore that we have to require boundedness) linear maps from $H$ to $\mathbb{C}$. When $H$ is finite-dimensional we know that $H \cong H^\star$ (there exists a bijective linear map between the vector spaces) but in quantum mechanics generically this is not the case.

In quantum mechanics elements of $H$ are written as $|\psi \rangle$ and elements of $H^\star$ are written as $\langle \psi|$. The first operator you wrote down is an element of $H \otimes H^\star$ ($A \otimes B$ is defined as the set $A \times B = \{(a,b)|a \in A, b \in B\}$ with operations $(a_1 + a_2,b) = (a_1,b) + (a_2,b)$, $(a,b_1 + b_2) = (a,b_1)+(a,b_2)$ and $\lambda (a,b) = (\lambda a,b) = (a,\lambda b)$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $A,B$ are both vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$, the inner product on $A \otimes B$ can also be derived from $A$ and $B$ (assuming there is an inner-product)). For $\dim(H) < \infty$ one can show that $H \otimes H^\star \cong \mathrm{End}(H)$ (i.e. linear maps from $H$ to $H$). This means that this operator can be represented as a matrix since it can be thought of as a linear map on $H$. The second however is just an element of $H \otimes H$, which is not isomorphic to $\mathrm{End}(H)$.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a storm in a notational teacup. Are you misconstruing your notation, expressly contrived for that ostensible purpose? 
You have an *n×n* matrix,
$$A=\sum_{ij}a_{ij}|i\rangle\langle j|,$$
juxtaposed to an $n^2$-dimensional ket vector,
$$|A'\rangle=\sum_{ij}a_{ij}|i\rangle \otimes |j\rangle. $$

The two are related, by the evident map
$$
\langle k| A |m\rangle = a_{km}= (\langle k|\otimes \langle m|   ) ~~|A'\rangle ~,
$$
where the tensor order is, of course, not transposed in the bra, as per standard physics notation.